Both my adult kids and their father (ex husband) dual citizens
Both my adult kids and their father  (now my ex husband) have dual citizenship with France. I was told at one point,  I would also be able to apply for dual citizenship because of my children. Now that they over her over 18 years old is that still a possibility?

What you are looking for is called obtaining French citizenship par déclaration. It is indeed possible to do that if you have children (or grand-children) who are French citizens but there are two additional requirements:

Being 65 or older
Residing in France since 25 years

So your children's age is not an issue but the scope is very restrictive and might not apply to you. It's only for people whose family is already centered on France and want to further secure their right to stay there in their old age.
Like everybody else, you can also get French citizenship through naturalization or by décret but you would have to qualify on your own, irrespective of your relationship with your children. Based on the facts you shared, I am afraid there is probably no expedited or simplified procedure available to you at this time.
Gaining citizenship would not have been easier if your children were younger (that's only relevant to get a residence permit, not citizenship). Residing in France is necessary in almost all cases, the main exception being the spouse of a French citizen.
